# How to convert HH.MM.SS (object type) column to HH:MM in python?

Tags: python, time, format

I have one column (245000 row) as time shown below:

```
Time

10.30.00
11.00.00
12.00.00
.
.
.
```

and want to convert HH:MM as like  time format.

```
10:30
11:00
12:00
```

I am trying to use this code

```
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/gokhankazar/Desktop/Veriler/SGK Kaza Verisi/veri2_rev01.xlsx")
df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%HH:%MM')
print(df)
```

get ValueError: time data '10.30.00  ' does not match format '%HH:%MM' (match)

There are lots of converting methods, but cannot find the solution of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_list = df['Time'].tolist()
output_list = [":".join(i.split('.')[:-1]) for i in your_list if len(i.split('.'))==3]
for time in output_list:
    print(time)
```

Comment: Thank you @wishmaster, it is well working, but I want to convert my column and write to excel again.It just give the result

Comment: @GokhanKazar then just store it in your df

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do below

```
foo= "10.30.30"
print(foo.replace(".",":")[:-3])
```

result '10:30'